I want Gmail api to read and write email using postman api. Without browser and UI interaction
I'm facing problem to use gmail api for my cypress test cases to read and write emails by using api's. But tried alot by reading different blog and watching videos, But nothing helped me out in better way.
import { google } from "googleapis";

Cypress.Commands.add("getLatestEmail", () => {
  // Authenticate with Gmail API
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: "path/to/your/credentials.json",
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"],
});
const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth });

// Fetch list of emails
return gmail.users.messages
.list({
  userId: "me",
  q: "is:inbox", // Filter by inbox
})
.then((response) => {
  // Get the latest email
  const latestEmailId = response.data.messages[0].id;

  // Fetch the latest email
  return gmail.users.messages.get({
    userId: "me",
    id: latestEmailId,
  });
})
.then((email) => {
  // Return email data
  return email.data;
});
});

Previously, I used gmail api, but everytime I was supposed to renew token. Is there any best solution where automation test using JavaScript  automatically generated all required thing to run gmail api?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It looks like googleapis is for NodeJs - but you are running it in the browser (via Cypress test).
Cypress provides a way to run in NodeJs via a task.
So, roughly translating your code from the custom command to a task
cypress.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const {google} = require('googleapis');

function getLatestEmail() {  
  // code from custom command goes here
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        getLatestEmail
      })
    },
  },
})

test
cy.task('getLatestEmail').then(email => {
  ...


It's good to go but still I have issue that, I've to update auth details with separate UI.

So still not working when used in task? Sounds like there are more errors in the  authenticate section. Can you use OAuth2?

I spent more than a month to fix these issues. But nothing found in good way

During that month, did you use OAuth2 or did you only try GoogleAuth?
